# How to add data result for four time into different textView in android?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have create a calculate program with some condition. I want to calculate and successive result for four times. Ex. the first result will pass to the first payment, then second result will pass data by getting the old result plus the new result from first payment. Finally calculate all result from them. I don't know how to keep the old result to plus the new result. How can I do it. Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private double result;
private double used;
private double price1;
private double price2;
private double price3;
private double price4;
private double price5;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText use_water = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    final TextView pay1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.payment1);
    final TextView pay2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.payment2);
    final TextView pay3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.payment3);
    final TextView pay4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.payment4);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            used = Double.parseDouble(use_water.getText().toString());
            if(used<=15){
                result = used * 550;
                pay1.setText(Double.toString(result)+" Reils");
            }
            else if(used<=25){
                result = used * 720;
                pay1.setText(Double.toString(result)+" Reils");
            }
            else if(used<=40){
                result = used * 1010;
                pay1.setText(Double.toString(result)+" Reils");
            }
            else {
                result = used * 1720;
                pay1.setText(Double.toString(result)+" Reils");
            }
            price2 = result + result;
            pay2.setText(Double.toString(result)+" Reils");
            price3 = price2+(result + result);
            pay3.setText(Double.toString(result)+" Reils");
            price4 = price3+(price2+(result + result));
            pay4.setText(Double.toString(result)+" Reils");
        }
    });
}
```

this example images
[image]

Comment: You probably need Text Watcher

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @Krish Do you ask me?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use `price2`, `price3` and `price4` as your `TextView`s content:

```
price2 = result + result;
pay2.setText(Double.toString(price2)+" Reils");
price3 = price2+(result + result);
pay3.setText(Double.toString(price3)+" Reils");
price4 = price3+(price2+(result + result));
pay4.setText(Double.toString(price4)+" Reils");
```

Comment: but the new result will replace the old one and i will get the new result.

Comment: no, `result` will keep its old value. Unless you're doing all of this multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reactive programming

For example,

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.payment1);;
TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.payment2);;
TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.payment3);;

textView1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //todo let textview2 know
        //like textview2.setText(result + Double.parseDouble(s) + "");
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you explain it? I am not sure how to use it.